# Configure MySQL server IP

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server which is tied to localhost. I would like to change it to an ip address, for example 192.168.x.x . I tried using the administrator from MySQL toolbench, but i am unable to find any option to configure it.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

-----------Edited-----------------

I have tried added the bind address in my.ini file

```
[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

bind-address = 192.168.x.x
```

I am able to ping the ip, and when i do a telnet the response is 5.1.46 community and some gibberish characters.

And i am still unable to connect to MySQL via my ip. Thanks...

Kevin

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @bernace Aside from the location of the my.cnf file, OS doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I sincerely hope you put a real IP address instead of `192.168.x.x`. Why bother hiding the IP address anyway?? It's not like we can hack you on `192.168.0.1` - we'd have better luck breaking into `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @ErikA, the OS will determine not just the location of the config file but even it's name. So yes, the OS is relevant. The name used in the question suggests it's a Windows system but it would of course be the wrong file entirely if the system is not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you haven't the permission to log as root from a host different from localhost.
Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html), so you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[`bind-address`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) in the configuration file or daemon command line.

Comment: Hi, i have tried the bind-address in the configuration file, and i am still unable to connect the MySQL via ip address.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `my.cnf` file:

```
bind-address = 192.168.x.x
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply... I have added in bind-address = 192.168.x.x in the my.ini as i am using windows XP.... Restarted MySQL service. But i am still unable to connect via 192.168.x.x. Using the MySQL Administrator i login as
serverhost: 192.168.x.x
username: root
password:""
Do i need to create a new connection for it??

Comment: Can you ping the address 192.168.x.x from your LAN?

Comment: yes.. i am able to ping it.

Comment: Am i missing out other configuration to it??

Comment: can you telnet to it (telnet 192.168.x.x 3306)?

Comment: Hi, I am not too sure what is telnet for, but when i did a telnet 192.168.x.x 3306. The reply was 5.1.46 community and some gibberish characters. So, is this the intended response when i telnet?? Btw, i am still unable to connect via my ip. Thanks for all the help guys..

Comment: Nivek - it was just to test if anything was listening on that IP:port. From the response you described, it sounds like mysql is indeed listening.

Comment: Erika, thanks for all your help. Just to check with you, when i type in the bind address in the my.ini file. I can place it anywhere in the text?? or do i have to place it at some specified place within the text??

Comment: Nivek - I don't have access to a `my.ini` file right now, but if its syntax is anything like the `my.cnf` file that is used in linux, the `bind-address` directive needs to be put in the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: Erika - Oh, i have not seen a my.cnf for linux and for your info, its my 1st time looking at the my.ini file. Alright, i have found the [mysqld] section. It has 1 in client section and the other in server section. So where do i place them??

Comment: As stated, you need to insert your `bind-address` directive in the server section, `[mysqld]`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall is disabled or well configured?

Mysql use TCP port 3306

Comment: Hi there, i have disable the windows firewall. And what do you meant by well configured?? Thanks

Comment: If your firewall is disabled, it isn't your problem. Well configured = configured to open Mysql port.